# Constructing Indptr for SciPy Sparse CSC Matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have many lists that represent a sparse matrix (i.e., the columns that have nonzero entries) that I need to represent as a SciPy sparse `csc_matrix`. However, note that there is only one row in my sparse matrix and so the list simply points to the columns within this row that has nonzero entries. For example:

```
sparse_input = [4, 10, 21]  # My lists are much, much longer but very sparse
```

This list tells me which columns within my single row sparse matrix where there are nonzero values. This is what the dense matrix would look like.

```
x = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])
```

I could use the `(data, (row, col))` syntax but since my lists are super long the `csc_matrix` takes a lot of time and memory to build. So, I was thinking about using the `indptr` interface but I'm having trouble figuring out how to quickly and automatically build the `indptr` directly from a given sparse list of nonzero column entries. I tried looking at `csr_matrix(x).indptr` and I see that the `indptr` looks like:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       3], dtype=int32)
```

I've read the SciPy docs and the [Sparse Matrix Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Compressed_sparse_row_(CSR,_CRS_or_Yale_format)) but I can't seem to come up with an efficient method to construct the `indptr` directly from a list of nonzero columns. It just feels like `indptr` shouldn't be this long in length considering that there are only three nonzero entries in the sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

How about just making the matrices, and exploring their attributs?

```
In [144]: from scipy import sparse                                                             
In [145]: x = np.array([[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]])                        

In [146]: M = sparse.coo_matrix(x)                                                             
In [147]: M                                                                                    
Out[147]: 
<1x22 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [148]: M.row                                                                                
Out[148]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
In [149]: M.col                                                                                
Out[149]: array([ 4, 10, 21], dtype=int32)
In [150]: M.data                                                                               
Out[150]: array([1, 1, 1])
```

csr:

```
In [152]: Mr = M.tocsr()                                                                       
In [153]: Mr.indptr                                                                            
Out[153]: array([0, 3], dtype=int32)
In [155]: Mr.indices                                                                           
Out[155]: array([ 4, 10, 21], dtype=int32)
In [156]: Mr.data                                                                              
Out[156]: array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

csc:

```
In [157]: Mc = M.tocsc()                                                                       
In [158]: Mc.indptr                                                                            
Out[158]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       3], dtype=int32)
In [159]: Mc.indices                                                                           
Out[159]: array([0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
In [160]: Mc.data                                                                              
Out[160]: array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int64)
```

And the direct `nonzero` on `x`:

```
In [161]: np.nonzero(x)                                                                        
Out[161]: (array([0, 0, 0]), array([ 4, 10, 21]))
```

For a 1 row matrix like this, I doubt if you'll save much time by creating the `csr` `indptr` directly.  Most of the work will be in the `nonzero` step.  But feel free to experiement.

===

Some timings

```
In [162]: timeit sparse.coo_matrix(x)                                                          
95.8 µs ± 110 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [163]: timeit sparse.csr_matrix(x)                                                          
335 µs ± 2.59 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [164]: timeit M.tocsr()                                                                     
115 µs ± 948 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [165]: timeit M.tocsc()                                                                     
117 µs ± 90.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [166]: sparse.csr_matrix?                                                                   
In [167]: timeit M.tocsc()                                                                     
117 µs ± 1.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [168]: timeit sparse.csc_matrix(x)                                                          
335 µs ± 257 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [169]: timeit sparse.coo_matrix(x).tocsr()                                                  
219 µs ± 3.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

I'm a little surprised that the `csr_matrix` is slower than `coo` followed by conversion.

Now let's try to make the matrix with `indptr` etc.

```
In [170]: timeit np.nonzero(x)                                                                 
2.52 µs ± 65.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [173]: timeit sparse.csr_matrix((Mr.data, Mr.indices, Mr.indptr))                           
92.5 µs ± 79.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [174]: %%timeit 
     ...: indices = np.nonzero(x)[1] 
     ...: data = np.ones_like(indices) 
     ...: indptr = np.array([0,len(indices)]) 
     ...: sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr)) 
     ...:  
     ...:                                                                                      
161 µs ± 605 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```